C++/Arduino store struct data in array
I'm writing a class for a Raspberry Pi Pico (using Arduino) that involves communicating via modbus. I am using structs to organise my data into ID data, status data, measurement data etc. I would like these structs to share the same memory as the modbus array to avoid a memcpy every time I change a variable or receive a message. I can do similar using arrays as follows:
uint16_t modbusData[255];
uint16_t offset = 10; //target address for array

struct DataStruct_t {
    uint16_t measCount = 3; //number of measurements
    uint16_t sampCount = 5; //number of samples containing measCount measurements
    uint16_t *data;  //raw data of length measCount*sampCount
};

DataStruct_t dataStruct;

dataStruct.data = &modbusData[offset];  //data is stored directly in modbus registers and accessed via pointer

uint16_t measurement0 = data[0]; //equal to modbusData[offset]

I would like to do something equivalent to the following instead. Currently it gives me type errors, as I can't make a DataStruct_t pointer point at a location in a uint16_t array. Is this possible or am I trying to do something dumb?
DataStruct_t *dataStruct;

dataStruct = &modbusData[offset];



You can cast your pointer. dataStruct = (DataStruct_t *)&modbusData[offset];. This is known as type punning and it's technically undefined behaviour so I don't know if it will work in practise, but it's worth a try.

That doesn't make much sense. After dataStruct = &modbusData[offset] (assuming for the sake of argument you got it to compile), what do you expect to be the value of dataStruct->measCount and dataStruct->sampCount? What do you expect dataStruct->data to point to?

@IgorTandetnik I would expect the same results as if I used memcpy to copy the struct in/out of the array:     memcpy(&dataStruct, modbusData + offset, sizeof(DataStruct_t));

Far as I can tell from your description, modbusData + offset doesn't contain the number of measurements or the number of samples, and it certainly does not contain a pointer. So what good do you expect memcpy(&dataStruct, modbusData + offset, sizeof(DataStruct_t)); to achieve? It'll just write some garbage into dataStruct, complete with an invalid pointer. It will not be equivalent to dataStruct.measCount = 3; dataStruct.sampCount = 5; dataStruct.data = &modbusData[offset]; which appears to be the desired end result.

@IgorTandetnik I think you misunderstand. If I memcpy a struct full of data into the array, then memcpy back from the populated array into a new struct, is the data the same, and is this supported behaviour?

Your struct is not "full of data" in any sense of the word I could think of. Your struct contains a pointer, presumably pointing to some data. When you memcpy a struct, it would copy the pointer, but not the data pointed to. Realize that sizeof(DataStruct_t) is a compile-time constant, something like 8 (two 16-bit integers and one pointer, say 32 bits - so 64 bits = 8 bytes total). These 8 bytes are all that memcpy will copy. That's probably not what you mean when you mention "full of data".

@IgorTandetnik ok, ignore the pointer - it's now a fixed length array. Can I do it now?

Show the updated code.
